# php register suddenly not working- was working previously, but there are no errors

Tags: php

I am creating a register page, and it was working fine, however now when I go to create a new user it isn't working. It just keeps saying user could not be created. There are no errors that are appearing. This is my php code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['passwordagain'])) {
$fmsg = null;
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$passwordRepeat = $_POST['passwordagain'];

if(strlen($username) < 2) {
    $fmsg = 'empty username';
}

if($fmsg === null && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $fmsg = 'invalid email';
}

if($fmsg === null && $password !== $passwordRepeat) {
    $fmsg = 'passwords don`t match';
}

if ($fmsg === null) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(user_id) as user_count FROM zz_login WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if(!is_bool($result)) {
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        if($user['user_count'] == 0) {
            $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO zz_login (`username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if ($result) {
                $smsg = "User Registered Successfully"; 
            } else {
                $fmsg = "User couldn`t be created";
            }
        } else {
            $fmsg = 'User already exists';
        }
    } else {
        $fmsg = 'ERR_QUERY_1';
    }
}

if($fmsg === null) {
    unset($fmsg);
}
}
```

If anyone has any answers as to why this could suddenly not work can you please let me know. As I have no idea, thank you

UPDATE: all other errors work, eg user already exists and passwords don't match

Comment: Did you try to echo `mysqli_error($conn)`?

Comment: @Phil I added it just before the end of the if ($fmsg === null) {} but it didn't do anything. Am I using this wrong?

Comment: @dean Sorry I am not sure what you mean. Could you explain more

Comment: check the query of the data to see if the user is already registered, also i think  null means empty why use $fmsg === null  instead $fmsg == null

Comment: @dean the user already exists works fine. When i try add someone with the same email it comes up with that error message as stated above. But when I try to add a brand new user it always says user cannot be created. I tried removing the = but there was no change

Comment: @CD6554, I think you should echo mysql err info right after `$fmsg = "User couldn`t be created";`.

Comment: remove the last '}' where  there is unset($fmsg);

Comment: @Phil this still didn't change anything

Comment: @dean why would I do that? then i would just get unexpected end of input???

Comment: i run your code and it had an extra } at the bottom if($fmsg === null) {
    unset($fmsg);
}
}// remove this

Comment: @dean when I remove it is says unexpected end of input. I need to keep it in

Comment: i have copied the entire code to my editor and i had an error check your code and you will find it

Comment: @dean well then you must have copied my code wrong because I need all the brackets

Comment: hmm.. ur yes, no errors, sorry

Comment: @dean do you know if it could be any other issue?

Comment: suggestion:  when i come into contact with the error i don't see or when the page fails to work properly , i trace back my codes by starting from what works well . so you said that the verification works,  from what works good re-create the code from there. you will finally get it.  programming sucks but its interesting.